# Plot from Excel sheet, 2 Columns, 1 of those columns with 2 categories

Tags: plotting, import, excel

I have the following Excel csv sheet:
[image]

It tells if an university is Public or Private, then how in debt they are in USD.
Control is only 1 or 2, (1 = Public, 2 = Private).

I want to make an statistic analysis between these 2 columns, comparing how much more debt there is for private universities. This means plotting Histograms, box-plots, etc. (I know how to plot those)

I also know how to Import all this data.

What I am missing is how to manipulate this data, specially in column CONTROL. I don't know how to "match" or "group" the 2 values of group and assign them to its corresponding DEBT value.

thanks in advance.

---

[Sample of 50 Universities in Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2hm0n3kiw8iu98/Sample.csv?dl=0)

The code I'm using to Import data is:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\cariasg\\Downloads\\Sample.csv", {"Data", Range[1, 50], {1, 2}}]
```

This one imports using a direct file path and only rows from 1 to 50 and columns 1 to 2.

Comment: Can you upload (a small sample of) the Excel file somewhere, as well as show the code you used?

Comment: added those two in the Answer section

Comment: Next time, please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/141315/edit) to include additional details instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  Use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html).

---

Suppose you've imported the data into a 2-column matrix `data`.  An example:

```
data = { {1, 3388}, {2, 5679}, {2, 4567}, {2,8764}, {1, "PrivacySuppressed"} }
```

First you can filter out `"PrivacySuppressed"` entries with something like

```
dataFiltered = DeleteCases[ data, {_, "PrivacySuppressed"} ]
```

Then you can split the data according to the first entry using [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) :

```
GroupBy[ dataFiltered, First ]
(* <| 1 -> {{1, 3388}}, 2 -> {{2, 5679}, {2, 4567}, {2, 8764}} |> *)
```

Or better yet, you can remove the first column with

```
dataSplit = GroupBy[ dataFiltered, First -> Last ]
(* <| 1 -> {3388}, 2 -> {5679, 4567, 8764} |> *)
```

Then you can access the list of entries using

```
dataSplit[1]
(* {3388} *)
dataSplit[2]
(* {5679, 4567, 8764} *)
```